# BaseOfCode present in PE+ executable

Tags: windows, jetbrains-ide, portable-executable, coff

The [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Debug/pe-format#optional-header-standard-fields-image-only) says that the `BaseOfCode` value is only present in PE files, not in PE+.  Looking at `notepad.exe` with dotPeek and with  PE Viewer seems to indicate that the `BaseOfCode` is present and consumed.

```
       0 1  2 3  4 5  6 7  8 9  A B  C D  E F
0x00E0 | 5045 0000 6486 0600 6a98 8957 0000 0000
0x00F0 | 0000 0000 f000 2200 0b02 0e00 0086 0100
0x0100 | 004e 0200 0000 0000 d087 0100 0010 0000
```

The two bytes at `0x00F8` signify that this is a PE+ header.  The `BaseOfCode` is the four bytes at `0x010C`.

Is the documentation (and myself) incorrect or are dotPeek and PE View
incorrect?

The fact that these bytes aren't zeroed out would imply that it the bytes are significant in some way.

Comment: No, BaseOfCode is there in both. It's BaseOfData that is absent from PE+ files.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError You're right.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the `BaseOfData`. It's present on PE32 (PE), not PE64 (PE+).